# Solaris 10: remote root ssh login

Tags: ssh, solaris

I am trying to enable root ssh login for a Solaris 10 VM (10.0.2.15) on a private netwrork. I have set PermitRootLogin to 'yes' in /etc/ssh/sshd_config as well as commenting out "CONSOLE" in /etc/default/login. I restarted the SSH service and then also reboot the VM because just restarting sshd did not seem to work.

From a Solaris 11 VM, when I try to login with the creds that work on the Console of the Solaris 10 VM, the login does not appear to work.

```
root@solaris11: ssh root@10.0.2.15
password:
password:
password:
Permission denied (gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive).
```

I have confirmed that the two hosts can see each other via ICMP "ping" exchanges and netcat:

```
root@solaris11: netcat -nvv 10.0.2.15 22
Connection to 10.0.2.15 22 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
SSH-2.0-Sun_SSH_2.2
```

What else I am missing to enable remote root login to this VM via ssh?

Comment: you restart ssh**d** service, I assume this is a typo. You also allow `passwordAUthentification yes` ?

Comment: Yes, thank you, I fixed the type. And yes I have passwords also enabled. I ended up creating a user account on both VMs with the same SSH keys and things work great in that respect. But the root ssh still does not work.